# OpenBSD eg++ 4.9.3: Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted

Tags: multithreading, c++11, g++, pthreads, openbsd

When trying to compile ansvif (a fuzzer) on OpenBSD with g++ (eg++) from the ports tree everything configures and compiles fine until I get to actually running the program in a place where it requires threading.

I try to compile like this:

```
AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.69 AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.15 aclocal
AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.69 AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.15 autoconf
AUTOCONF_VERSION=2.69 AUTOMAKE_VERSION=1.15 automake -a
CXX=/usr/ports/pobj/gcc-4.9.3/bin/eg++ ./configure
make
```

Then I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
Abort trap (core dumped)
```

This seems to only be reproducible on **OpenBSD 6.0** with g++ 4.9.3 from *ports*.  You can't compile the code with the built in g++, as the code requires C++11.

The backtrace looks like this:

```
GNU gdb 6.3
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "amd64-unknown-openbsd6.0".
Core was generated by `ansvif'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00000a5d2326029a in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000a5d2326029a in ?? ()
#1  0x00000a5d23274039 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000a5d23280c0a in ?? ()
#3  0x00000a5a441cea80 in ?? ()
#4  0xffffffdf00000202 in ?? ()
#5  0xf296d56c8d2c4acf in ?? ()
#6  0x00000a5c54dc0198 in ?? ()
#7  0x00000a5a43d8b165 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The same compiles and works correctly under Linux and Windows (with MinGW).

I've read some similar issues that say its a compiler bug but the hacky 'fix' that they provide for it on SO doesn't seem to help (using `-Wl,--no-as-needed`) in this case.

Comment: AFAIK the 4 release of GCC uses the old C++98 standard as default (with GCC extensions). `std::thread` is a C++11 feature (as you rightly says). That means you need to build with the `-std=c++11` flag. Do you build with that flag? You might also need to use the `-pthread` flag both when compiling and linking, to make sure POSIX threads are enables. Do you build with that flag too?

Comment: Yes, I'm building with `ansvif_LDFLAGS = -I./include/gzstream -I./include/xml_writer -I./src/linux -pthread` in the Makefile.am and `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` in the configure.ac files.  At compile time you can see it is using -pthread and -std=c++11.

Answer (score 1):

You're linking the code against `libstdc++`. You should use `libestdc++` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work, though I also did find another error in my Makefile.am when I was going through to change it.  An `else` wasn't where it was intended to be so some code wasn't being passed to the compiler at all.  You lead me in the right direction!

Comment: You earned an honorable mention in the ansvif Wiki for your assistance!